# How to join two sql select statements side by side

Tags: sql, database

I have two select statements and would like to join the results(cat and dog) side by side. Could someone please explain to me how I could do it. I've been trying for a while but can't get it to work.

```
SELECT kernel.dog_id, animal.name as dog
FROM appointment
LEFT JOIN animal
ON  kernel.dog_id=animal.animal_id;

SELECT kernel.cat_id, animal.name as cat
FROM appointment
LEFT JOIN animal
ON  kernel.cat_id=animal.animal_id;
```

Comment: I'm trying to to use the UNION ALL between them but with the results side by side on the same table rather than one on top of the other if you get what I mean.

Comment: Do you mean the output should be one row like this: "dog_id, dog, cat_id, cat"? Also, is kernel the same table as appointment?

Comment: Yes that's the way I want the output to be, and yes kernel's the same as output. I've corrected it in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT kernel.dog_id, D.name as dog , C.name as cat
FROM appointment A
LEFT JOIN animal D ON  kernel.dog_id=D.animal_id;
LEFT JOIN animal C ON  kernel.cat_id=C.animal_id;
```

Comment: Thanks do I leave the "D.name", "C.name" and A, D and C as they are or do I need to replace them. Sorry if its a dumb question, I'm new to sql.

Comment: @aab you should use A,D and C as is! or you can change it in whole syntax. ;)